# Why do we care about positively or negatively of $a_{n}$ when we have a series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Wikipedia claims:
[image]

I know that if for all $n\ge N$ ($N \in \mathbb N^{+}$) $a_n$ is not positive or negative then we don't have an alternating series, but does there exist any other reason for that?

Assume we've been given some series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}a_{n}$ , and we don't know which one of them is an alternating series (and assume we don't care about that) , then if $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$,and $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n\ge N}$ is monotonic , then can we say the series converges? based on [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) I think such series is convergent, because besides the two mentioned conditions we know that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(-1\right)^{n}\right|\le1$ .

I think we should check if for all $n\ge N$ ($N \in \mathbb N^{+}$) $a_n$ is positive or negative if the question asks us to find out whether the series is an alternating series or it is not and if the question asks us for determining the convergence of the series then we just need to check whether then series satisfies the Dirichlet's test conditions or it does not.

Comment: Note that $\lim_na_n=0,\ \{a_n\}$ is monotonic $\implies a_n$ is always positive or always negative. So you can prove the convergence of such sequences either using the alternating test or the Dirichlet test.

Comment: @trisct, can you prove that?

Comment: This is obvious. $a_n\nearrow 0\implies a_n\leq0$ and $a_n\searrow 0\implies a_n\geq0$.

Comment: If we have a series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}a_{n}$ and we've been asked for determining the convergence of the series, then what should we check?

Comment: In general there is no answer. No one ever said such a series must satisfy some criterion you learned in the books to converge. Neither has anyone said such a series can only satisfy one of these criterions. You can check whatever you want. But if it comes from an exercise, there's a big chance that you should check the criterion taught in the corresponding chapter.

Comment: you are right, that's why there exist lots of convergence tests, but can I say if such series satisfies the two conditions " $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ and $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n\ge N}$ is monotonic" then it converges?

Comment: I think you've proved it in your question.

Comment: @trisct, but I'm not sure about that, since Thomas calculus requires the condition "for all $n\ge N$ ($N \in \mathbb N^{+}$) $a_n$ is positive or negative", thought I think we need not to check that, since by Dirichlet test if such series satisfies the two previous conditions then it does converge

Comment: You don't actually need Dirichlet's test. A sequence that tends to $0$ monotonically must be all positive or all negative. You can still use the alternating test. I think the first condition ($a_n\geq0$) in the Thomas book is redundant. Why don't you mention this to your teacher?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107132/discussion-between-user715522-and-trisct).